# how to get the same code source working in mobile as an other app

Tags: android, android-install-apk

i was working with a source code of an application in eclipse in order to create an application
what i want is to create two applications the same view but with some differents in the content.
the proleme is when i change the database content
an extract it as an apk file
the apps cannot being installed together
when i install the second one i should delete the first app to install the second
that mean the phone think that this is the same application
so what can i do to make the phone accept installing the both apps
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default package name and update the same in manifest file. You can also change the app name for one application so that both applications dont have the same names. But this is not mandatory.

Comment: Change app package name